# How to pause Tor with new 3.5 firefox bundle (no Vidalia)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, firefox

With Vidalia I would stop Tor, change my firewall profile, and then use regular Firefox.  I could switch back over the same way, and my TorBrowser tabs were still opened.  With this new setup, when I switch my firewall (to Block Tor), Tor keeps trying to connect, cycling through different servers, and of course it keeps failing.  How to I pause/stop Tor with this new 3.5 bundle?  If I kill the Tor process, the browser stays open, but when I restart Tor (using the executable in the directory) it doesn't work.  It's running in the process list, but there's no connectivity online (the browser).  Also, this causes the browser to eat the CPU at 99% until I kill the browser process.  (Switching the firewall profile is what initiates the browser eating the CPU.)

Windows XP SP3 w/all updates.

Comment: The TBB version is quite old. I'd expect that you find ways with newer versions.